# unicorn-worker-killer- why is it a problem if multiple Unicorn workers are killed at the same time?

Tags: rack, unicorn

From the `unicorn-worker-killer` [README](https://github.com/kzk/unicorn-worker-killer), I see the following comment in the notes about the `Unicorn::WorkerKiller::Oom` module:

> memory_limit_min and memory_limit_max specify the min and max of
>   maximum memory in bytes per worker. The actual limit is decided by
>   rand() between memory_limit_min and memory_limit_max per worker, to
>   prevent all workers to be dead at the same time.

My question is: why would it be a problem if all workers were killed at the same time?  What's the worst-case and likely-case scenarios if that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Each worker process in Unicorn handles a request at time. If all workers happen to be busy while a new request is received, this will be queued by the master process until a worker is free to handle it.

Similarly, in the event all of the worker processes are suddenly killed at the same time, any new request will be queued until at least a new worker is respawn. Unicorn handles this situation seamlessly, but forking a new process is relatively slow so you should try avoiding being in this situation if possible.